# New message when rebooting from login screen: Authentication is required for rebooting the system while an application asked to inhibit it

Tags: login, reboot, authentication

A new auth prompt has started popping up in the past few days (see title) (Ubuntu 18.04). This happens about half the time, anecdotally, when rebooting from the login screen without having logged in.

Thanks to [this discussion](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1713686), I was able to figure out that the relevant action, `org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-ignore-inhibit`, is configured in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy` (the link specifies a different file, but it's from 2011, so no surprise, things have changed). I think, given that, I can disable this action.

However, what I'd really like to do is find out which application is asking to inhibit rebooting and why. I imagine at least the "which" part can be answered via `journalctl`, but I don't know what to look for. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

**EDIT:** Using WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer, I was able to find lines like the following in `journalctl`:

```
... Operator of unix-session:c2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:randy to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-ignore-inhibit for system-bus-name::1.40 [/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart] (owned by unix-user:gdm)
```

So I guess `gdm` is the culprit. However, I'm still not sure why this is happening. I'll emphasize again that I was not logged in when the inhibitor was triggered.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of all systemd inhibitors with this:

```
$ systemd-inhibit --list

     Who: rick (UID 1000/rick, PID 2358/unity-settings-)
    What: sleep
     Why: GNOME needs to lock the screen
    Mode: delay

     Who: rick (UID 1000/rick, PID 2358/unity-settings-)
    What: handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key
     Why: GNOME handling keypresses
    Mode: block

     Who: NetworkManager (UID 0/root, PID 1189/NetworkManager)
    What: sleep
     Why: NetworkManager needs to turn off networks
    Mode: delay

     Who: Unattended Upgrades Shutdown (UID 0/root, PID 1372/unattended-upgr)
    What: shutdown
     Why: Stop ongoing upgrades or perform upgrades before shutdown
    Mode: delay

     Who: rick (UID 1000/rick, PID 2358/unity-settings-)
    What: handle-lid-switch
     Why: Multiple displays attached
    Mode: block

5 inhibitors listed.
```

However the list doesn't change after you open a file for editing for example. You can use this instead:

```
$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.GetInhibitors

method return time=1573403207.555584 sender=:1.49 -> destination=:1.1853 serial=7743 reply_serial=2
   array [
   ]

$ gedit temp &

# Now type some text into gedit but don't save the file

$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.GetInhibitors

method return time=1573403241.678869 sender=:1.49 -> destination=:1.1855 serial=7747 reply_serial=2
   array [
      object path "/org/gnome/SessionManager/Inhibitor1727"
   ]
```

In the first instance there are no inhibitor locks. We edit a file in gedit and in the second instance a lock exists. However it doesn't actually tell us the name `gedit`.

Comment: Please see my question edit.

Comment: gdm is user account for gnome desktop manager. It is logged in when you aren't to control login screen options.

Comment: Any idea why it would be inhibiting reboot in this situation? Possibly that's already answered from the log line, but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: I'm not sure. I imagine not may people go to the login screen just to reboot so it's probably not tested very much.

Comment: Fair. For context, there's a bug with my motherboard where the network interface doesn't come up on the first boot, so I reboot from the login screen at least once a day. In any event, thanks for your guidance.