# Shut Down Authentication Required Due To Application Inhibiting - Then Stalled At Start-Up

Tags: authentication

Ubuntu 20.04.5 Desktop

I never before observed this authentication required notice for powering off my laptop on Ubuntu. But now I get it every time I shut down the system . . .

[image]

Here are the current processes on the laptop:

```
$ ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.0 168740 11888 ?        Ss   11:04   0:03 /sbin/init sp
root           2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [kthreadd]
root           3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [rcu_gp]
root           4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [rcu_par_gp]
root           5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [netns]
root           7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kworker/0:0H
root           9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:02 [kworker/0:1H
root          10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [mm_percpu_wq
root          11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [rcu_tasks_ru
root          12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [rcu_tasks_tr
root          13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:01 [ksoftirqd/0]
root          14  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        I    11:04   1:08 [rcu_sched]
root          15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [migration/0]
root          16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [idle_inject/
root          18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [cpuhp/0]
root          19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [cpuhp/1]
root          20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [idle_inject/
root          21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [migration/1]
root          22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:18 [ksoftirqd/1]
root          24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kworker/1:0H
root          25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [cpuhp/2]
root          26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [idle_inject/
root          27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [migration/2]
root          28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:01 [ksoftirqd/2]
root          30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kworker/2:0H
root          31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [cpuhp/3]
root          32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [idle_inject/
root          33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [migration/3]
root          34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:02 [ksoftirqd/3]
root          36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kworker/3:0H
root          37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root          38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [inet_frag_wq
root          39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [kauditd]
root          40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root          41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [oom_reaper]
root          42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [writeback]
root          43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:03 [kcompactd0]
root          44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   11:04   0:00 [ksmd]
root          45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   11:04   0:00 [khugepaged]
root          92  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root          93  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kblockd]
root          94  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [blkcg_punt_b
root          97  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:03 [kworker/1:1H
root          98  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [tpm_dev_wq]
root          99  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [ata_sff]
root         100  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [md]
root         101  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [edac-poller]
root         102  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root         103  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [watchdogd]
root         106  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [kswapd0]
root         107  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [ecryptfs-kth
root         109  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kthrotld]
root         110  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [acpi_thermal
root         113  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [vfio-irqfd-c
root         114  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:02 [kworker/3:1H
root         115  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:02 [kworker/2:1H
root         116  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [mld]
root         117  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [ipv6_addrcon
root         126  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kstrp]
root         127  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    11:04   0:17 [kworker/2:1-
root         130  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [zswap-shrink
root         131  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:28 [kworker/u9:0
root         138  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [charger_mana
root         190  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root         191  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root         192  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root         193  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root         195  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [irq/51-DELL0
root         216  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    11:04   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root         217  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
root         218  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    11:04   0:00 [usb-storage]
root         219  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [uas]
root         240  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:03 [jbd2/sda2-8]
root         241  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [ext4-rsv-con
root         279  0.0  0.4 126556 72984 ?        S<s  11:04   0:02 /lib/systemd/
root         306  0.0  0.0   2496   508 ?        S    11:04   0:00 bpfilter_umh
root         318  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [ipmi-msghand
root         322  0.0  0.0  25508  7972 ?        Ss   11:04   0:01 /lib/systemd/
root         457  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [irq/128-mei_
root         488  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [card0-crtc0]
root         490  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [card0-crtc1]
root         491  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [card0-crtc2]
root         496  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [cfg80211]
root         497  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kmemstick]
root         506  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [ath10k_wq]
root         507  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [ath10k_aux_w
root         508  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [ath10k_tx_co
root         543  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   1:44 [gfx]
root         544  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [comp_1.0.0]
root         545  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [comp_1.0.1]
root         546  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [comp_1.0.2]
root         547  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [comp_1.0.3]
root         548  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [comp_1.0.4]
root         549  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [comp_1.0.5]
root         550  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [comp_1.0.6]
root         551  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:00 [comp_1.0.7]
root         552  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:05 [sdma0]
root         553  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:04   0:24 [sdma1]
root         562  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:04   0:00 [kworker/u9:2
root         620  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   11:05   0:00 [cryptd]
systemd+     899  0.0  0.0  24812 12936 ?        Ss   11:05   0:05 /lib/systemd/
systemd+     901  0.0  0.0  90908  5952 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /lib/systemd/
root         967  0.0  0.0 247728  8200 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:01 /usr/lib/acco
root         968  0.0  0.0   2548   776 ?        Ss   11:05   0:04 /usr/sbin/acp
avahi        974  0.0  0.0   8480  3460 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 avahi-daemon:
root         978  0.0  0.0   8396  4532 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /usr/lib/blue
root         980  0.0  0.0  18056  2960 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/cro
root         981  0.0  0.0  37352  9188 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/cup
message+     982  0.0  0.0  10148  6812 ?        Ss   11:05   0:07 /usr/bin/dbus
root         983  0.0  0.1 271376 19916 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:07 /usr/sbin/Net
root         990  0.0  0.0  81900  3544 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:06 /usr/sbin/irq
root         992  0.0  0.0  13888  4516 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
root         994  0.0  0.1  48628 20588 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/pyth
root         998  0.0  0.0 250172 10892 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:01 /usr/lib/poli
syslog      1001  0.0  0.0 224528  5368 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsy
root        1009  0.0  0.2 1170324 47380 ?       Ssl  11:05   0:13 /usr/lib/snap
root        1013  0.0  0.0 244252  5744 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
root        1016  0.0  0.0  17468  8116 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /lib/systemd/
root        1021  0.0  0.0 134904  9352 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:06 /usr/sbin/the
root        1022  0.0  0.0 467920 14440 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/lib/udis
daemon      1023  0.0  0.0   3804  2236 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
avahi       1029  0.0  0.0   8348   328 ?        S    11:05   0:00 avahi-daemon:
root        1063  1.5  0.1  23628 20448 ?        SNs  11:05   9:52 /usr/sbin/pre
root        1076  0.0  0.0 178584 12864 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/cup
colord      1082  0.0  0.0 254988 14536 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
root        1086  0.0  0.0 315116 11412 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/Mod
mongodb     1172  0.8  0.4 981396 75700 ?        Ssl  11:05   5:15 /usr/bin/mong
root        1176  0.0  0.0 402356  7740 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /snap/canonic
root        1191  0.1  0.3 1503516 54396 ?       Ssl  11:05   0:49 /usr/bin/cont
root        1211  0.0  0.0  12184  6732 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 sshd: /usr/sb
root        1215  0.0  0.0 248284  8640 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/gdm
root        1232  0.0  0.1 126808 22876 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/pyth
root        1234  0.0  0.0 175456  9020 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 gdm-session-w
redis       1240  0.3  0.0  61428  4668 ?        Ssl  11:05   2:20 /usr/bin/redi
gdm         1269  0.0  0.0  19680 10212 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /lib/systemd/
gdm         1270  0.0  0.0 104612  3864 ?        S    11:05   0:00 (sd-pam)
mysql       1280  1.5  2.4 2384896 393508 ?      Ssl  11:05   9:57 /usr/sbin/mys
gdm         1285  0.0  0.1 1038476 18512 ?       S<sl 11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/puls
gdm         1287  0.0  0.1 733548 25264 ?        SNsl 11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1288  0.0  0.0 172692  6512 tty1     Ssl+ 11:05   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3
gdm         1290  0.0  0.5 1412536 95272 tty1    Sl+  11:05   0:01 /usr/lib/xorg
gdm         1294  0.0  0.0   7380  4324 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus
rtkit       1295  0.0  0.0 152936  3016 ?        SNsl 11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1308  0.0  0.0 248392  7604 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1325  0.0  0.0 312812  6352 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1332  0.0  0.0 322936  9604 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:01 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1340  0.0  0.0 244352  5712 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1355  0.0  0.0 244552  5824 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1359  0.0  0.2 558368 34420 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1380  0.0  0.0 397168  9048 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1388  0.0  0.0 246760  6208 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         1439  0.0  0.0 325400  8664 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:02 /usr/libexec/
root        1502  0.0  0.0 261068  9952 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:06 /usr/lib/upow
gdm         2245  0.0  0.0   5296  1088 tty1     S+   11:05   0:00 dbus-run-sess
gdm         2246  0.0  0.0   7672  4668 tty1     S+   11:05   0:00 dbus-daemon -
gdm         2277  0.0  0.0 492740 15244 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         2787  0.0  0.0 305732  6916 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         2822  0.0  0.0   7248  3808 tty1     S+   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus
gdm         4009  0.0  1.3 4237908 226720 tty1   Sl+  11:05   0:06 /usr/bin/gnom
gdm         4359  0.0  0.0 319528  8212 tty1     Sl   11:05   0:00 ibus-daemon -
gdm         4362  0.0  0.0 245172  6896 tty1     Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4364  0.0  0.1 196760 16576 tty1     Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4369  0.0  0.0 245152  7172 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4378  0.0  0.0 162840  7648 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4382  0.0  0.0 244244  4824 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4398  0.0  0.1 2742240 26532 tty1    Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/gjs 
gdm         4407  0.0  0.0 156236  5612 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4410  0.0  0.0 473740 10884 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:02 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4412  0.0  0.0 343872 16056 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4414  0.0  0.1 653896 20360 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4419  0.0  0.1 344572 17728 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4420  0.0  0.0 256928 11252 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4424  0.0  0.0 465784  6008 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4428  0.0  0.0 397908 10276 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4432  0.0  0.0 382500 15948 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4434  0.0  0.1 834820 20484 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4439  0.0  0.0 171344  7036 tty1     Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4440  0.0  0.0 244192  5840 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4443  0.0  0.0 328236  8828 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4445  0.0  0.0 318544  6624 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4450  0.0  0.0 320608  7676 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:04 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4452  0.0  0.1 492908 18064 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
gdm         4488  0.0  0.0 350864 14988 tty1     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
root        4524  0.0  0.4 1446376 69172 ?       Ssl  11:05   0:15 /usr/bin/dock
whoopsie    4528  0.0  0.0 327064 15604 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/whoo
kernoops    4531  0.0  0.0  11264   444 ?        Ss   11:05   0:04 /usr/sbin/ker
kernoops    4534  0.0  0.0  11264   444 ?        Ss   11:05   0:04 /usr/sbin/ker
root        4684  0.0  0.0 1074872 3292 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/dock
root        4690  0.0  0.0 1222080 3200 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/dock
root        4704  0.0  0.0 1074872 3332 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/dock
root        4710  0.0  0.0 1222080 3376 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/dock
root        4725  0.0  0.0 712656 10236 ?        Sl   11:05   0:06 /usr/bin/cont
root        4745  0.0  0.2 743568 33124 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:14 /portainer
root        6984  0.0  0.0 323304 11012 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 gdm-session-w
sandbar     6995  0.0  0.0  20160 10804 ?        Ss   11:05   0:01 /lib/systemd/
sandbar     6996  0.0  0.0 170148  3988 ?        S    11:05   0:00 (sd-pam)
sandbar     7002  0.0  0.1 1828508 21536 ?       S<sl 11:05   0:12 /usr/bin/puls
sandbar     7004  0.0  0.1 735340 28412 ?        SNsl 11:05   0:02 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7007  0.0  0.0   8848  5836 ?        Ss   11:05   0:01 /usr/bin/dbus
sandbar     7014  0.0  0.0 248856  7888 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/gnom
sandbar     7016  0.0  0.0 248392  7712 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7032  0.0  0.0 378348  5488 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7039  0.0  0.0 322964  9860 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7046  0.0  0.0 244352  5672 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7050  0.0  0.0 244552  5904 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7054  0.0  0.2 558396 34588 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
root        7059  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:05   0:00 [krfcommd]
sandbar     7065  0.0  0.0 323436  8896 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7072  0.0  0.0 246760  6484 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7076  0.0  0.0 325400  8896 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:02 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7083  0.0  0.0 172692  6504 tty2     Ssl+ 11:05   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3
sandbar     7085  3.6  0.6 1389416 112976 tty2   Sl+  11:05  23:27 /usr/lib/xorg
sandbar     7119  0.0  0.0 197112 14136 tty2     Sl+  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7206  0.0  0.0   6040   456 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-
sandbar     7227  0.0  0.0 305640  6680 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7232  0.0  0.0   7380  4232 ?        S    11:05   0:01 /usr/bin/dbus
sandbar     7241  0.0  0.0  98700  4260 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7248  0.0  0.0 567312 16220 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7262  4.9  2.2 4896584 363100 ?      Ssl  11:05  32:21 /usr/bin/gnom
sandbar     7293  0.0  0.0 319572  8240 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 ibus-daemon -
sandbar     7297  0.0  0.0 245196  6960 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7298  0.0  0.2 286132 34304 ?        Sl   11:05   0:01 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7300  0.0  0.1 208120 29968 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7304  0.0  0.0 245152  7276 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7315  0.0  0.0 162840  7672 ?        Sl   11:05   0:06 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7319  0.0  0.0 244252  4596 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7322  0.0  0.1 581744 20480 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7330  0.0  0.1 1013544 25600 ?       Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7339  0.0  0.1 1126112 30820 ?       Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7348  0.0  0.0 156604  5912 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7354  0.0  0.1 682088 29768 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7368  0.0  0.1 2668612 26916 ?       Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/gjs 
sandbar     7376  0.0  0.0 322656  8208 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7389  0.0  0.0 318564  6400 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7390  0.0  0.1 599060 32008 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:01 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7392  0.0  0.0 382520 16156 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7393  0.0  0.0 320984  8048 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:04 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7394  0.0  0.1 356380 31044 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7395  0.0  0.2 1305104 34448 ?       Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7396  0.0  0.1 430436 30968 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7397  0.0  0.0 256928 11172 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7398  0.0  0.0 465784  6000 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7399  0.0  0.0 244192  5964 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7402  0.0  0.0 473888 10764 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:02 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7403  0.0  0.0 471528  8488 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7406  0.0  0.0 328256  9092 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7409  0.0  0.0 467600  7416 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7411  0.0  0.1 355636 29900 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7414  0.0  0.0 396728  7996 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7415  0.0  0.1 356424 31772 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7448  0.0  0.0 231804  6344 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7462  0.0  0.0 350864 15112 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7465  0.0  0.3 512020 59436 ?        Sl   11:05   0:11 /usr/lib/x86_
sandbar     7474  0.0  0.3 652792 61256 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7483  0.0  0.0 321580  8536 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_
sandbar     7487  0.0  0.0 171340  7076 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     7499  0.0  0.3 452156 53056 ?        Sl   11:05   0:01 /usr/bin/pyth
sandbar     7564  0.0  0.9 1059552 160756 ?      Sl   11:05   0:10 /snap/snap-st
sandbar     7587  0.0  0.0 613672  6756 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
root        7592  0.0  0.0   2600  1904 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 fusermount -o
sandbar     9139  0.0  0.3 346408 64480 ?        Sl   11:05   0:00 /usr/bin/pyth
sandbar     9780  0.0  0.0  43992  6648 ?        Ss   11:05   0:00 /usr/lib/blue
sandbar     9833  0.0  0.0 619080 11540 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     9837  0.0  0.3 1104044 56832 ?       Ssl  11:05   0:02 /usr/libexec/
sandbar     9873  0.8  1.5 3766048 254524 ?      SLl  11:05   5:34 ./jetbrains-t
sandbar     9878  0.0  0.0  12296  2372 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:00 /home/sandbar
sandbar     9981  0.0  0.1 629284 17564 ?        Sl   11:06   0:01 zeitgeist-dat
sandbar     9992  0.0  0.0 395668  9276 ?        Ssl  11:06   0:00 /usr/bin/zeit
sandbar    10000  0.0  0.1 272808 17660 ?        Ssl  11:06   0:00 /usr/lib/zeit
sandbar    14363  0.0  0.0 170956  6536 ?        Ssl  11:06   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar    14366  0.0  0.2 473836 44204 ?        Sl   11:06   0:02 update-notifi
sandbar    14368  0.0  1.8 987904 299308 ?       Sl   11:06   0:09 /usr/bin/gnom
sandbar    16227  0.0  0.0 244736  6304 ?        Ssl  11:07   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar    16231  0.0  0.0   3980   200 ?        Ss   11:07   0:00 server --sh -
sandbar    72240  0.0  0.1 720064 26320 ?        Sl   11:20   0:01 /usr/bin/snap
root      227413  0.0  0.0  19788  3396 ?        S    12:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRO
root      227414  0.0  0.1  87968 18028 ?        Ss   12:00   0:00 timeshift --c
root      227437  0.0  0.0  18404  1004 ?        D    12:00   0:00 mount /dev/sd
sandbar   698210  0.0  0.2 443808 37796 ?        Ssl  14:04   0:03 /usr/libexec/
gdm       698298  0.0  0.0 170936  6316 ?        Ssl  14:04   0:00 /usr/libexec/
root      844200  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        I    14:44   0:39 [kworker/1:0-
root     1181396  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    16:24   0:08 [kworker/3:1-
root     1979209  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    20:29   0:03 [kworker/0:1-
root     1979214  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    20:29   0:00 [kworker/1:1-
root     2042017  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    20:50   0:02 [kworker/u8:2
root     2148803  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    21:24   0:00 [kworker/0:0-
root     2162295  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    21:28   0:00 [kworker/2:2-
root     2183775  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    21:34   0:00 [kworker/3:2-
root     2210553  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    21:42   0:00 [kworker/u8:3
sandbar  2210555  0.0  0.0   2600   540 ?        S    21:42   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar  2210564  0.0  0.0   2600   604 ?        S    21:42   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar  2210565  0.0  0.0 170276  5768 ?        Sl   21:42   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar  2210567  0.0  0.0   2968  1512 ?        S    21:42   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar  2210568 22.5  2.3 11584492 383732 ?     Sl   21:42   2:47 /app/lib/fire
sandbar  2210660  0.0  0.2 212632 36924 ?        Sl   21:42   0:00 /app/lib/fire
sandbar  2210712  0.1  0.5 2434016 83320 ?       Sl   21:42   0:01 /app/lib/fire
sandbar  2215717  5.2  0.9 2493428 149120 ?      Sl   21:43   0:33 /app/lib/fire
sandbar  2223038  0.0  0.4 2411824 76568 ?       Sl   21:45   0:00 /app/lib/fire
root     2224342  0.0  0.0   7172  1804 ?        S    21:46   0:00 dbus-launch -
root     2224343  0.0  0.0   7116  2428 ?        Ss   21:46   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus
root     2224346  0.0  0.0 156236  5476 ?        Sl   21:46   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar  2229478  3.1  1.3 2586876 216836 ?      Sl   21:47   0:12 /app/lib/fire
sandbar  2232085  0.0  0.3 2403120 61976 ?       Sl   21:48   0:00 /app/lib/fire
root     2239871  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    21:50   0:00 [kworker/2:0-
root     2239876  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    21:50   0:00 [kworker/3:0-
root     2241168  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    21:50   0:00 [kworker/u8:0
root     2243746  0.0  0.0 293148 15892 ?        Ssl  21:51   0:00 /usr/lib/pack
sandbar  2246323  0.0  0.0 396732  8408 ?        Sl   21:52   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar  2246337  0.0  0.0 323660  8488 ?        Sl   21:52   0:00 /usr/libexec/
root     2248909  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    21:52   0:00 [kworker/0:2-
sandbar  2251507  0.1  0.3 2402876 59528 ?       Sl   21:53   0:00 /app/lib/fire
sandbar  2251535  0.2  0.3 2402876 59840 ?       Sl   21:53   0:00 /app/lib/fire
sandbar  2255430  9.5  0.3 824576 52128 ?        Ssl  21:54   0:00 /usr/libexec/
sandbar  2255438  1.0  0.0  20316  6056 pts/0    Ss   21:54   0:00 bash
sandbar  2255486  0.0  0.0  20140  3304 pts/0    R+   21:54   0:00 ps aux
~$ active
```

I'd like to get rid of this unnecesary password demand but I don't know quite how.

**EDIT 1**

I deferred taking the actions suggested last night. Then after another prolonged shut-down (a lot of whizzing on the backup HDD - I eventually just held the power button off till it shut down) it would not start up. It **stalls** the start-up process at some network process.

[image: Screenshot at start-up stop]

I suspect that a recent Ubuntu 20.04.5 update has something to do with this.

Looks like I have to reboot from a USB key and roll back to over a week ago.

Before doing a rollback (I fear losing all my Ubuntu configs, maybe > 50 of them now) I saw this thread:

https://linuxdicasesuporte.blogspot.com/2019/05/ubuntu-nao-inicia-apos-started-gnome.html?m=1

(Please use the Translate button on the top right)

This did not work unfortunately.

The #WaylandEnable=false line was already uncommented.

When I commented it, I got past the boot stall and onto the Ubuntu login screen. However after entering my password it did not bring me to my desktop environment for my user account: it just returned me to the Ubuntu login screen as if I'd never entered my password.

Using a USB boot key I tried restoring with Timeshift off the backup. But I could not "see into" the backup drive and when I launched Timeshift it immediately started a backup on it - a process I could only stop by killing the process and then removing Timeshift from the applications installed on the bootable USB key.

**EDIT 2**

Nothing for it but to reboot in recovery mode and do a Timeshift restore via CLI. This failed due to a segment error.

Luckily I had a SDD backup to 4 weeks ago and I achieved a restoration from this. No matter what I did I could not mount the HDD backup - there was always an operation pending. Googling this issue told me I probably had a damaged HDD - something I should have suspected after the earlier noisy whizzing at shut down.

With new confidence I applied the 20.04.5 updates to the present date and restarted. No issues.

So the moral is **DON'T DEPEND ON A SINGLE BACKUP DRIVE !**

There is also some wisdom in what [this guy says about 3 backups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFO6NyLIP7M) on different media.

Comment: Searching for the message "authentication is required..." led me to https://askubuntu.com/q/1187748/1186757

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New message when rebooting from login screen: Authentication is required for rebooting the system while an application asked to inhibit it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187748/new-message-when-rebooting-from-login-screen-authentication-is-required-for-reb)

Comment: @Bodo and Artur.   I found it's *not an Ubuntu version/update problem*. It was just a failed HDD used for backup. The backup was activated every hour and at system start-up and shut-down. It couldn't complete the latter initiallly and I dismissed the noise from the HDD as a sign of failure. Afterwards it probably interfered with the usual start-up processes. My bacon was saved by having an SSD backup to recently. Thanks for assistance.